# In OS X, Firefox 26, Java 7u51 Liveconnect is broken?

Tags: java, macos, firefox, applet, liveconnect

The applets are working in Windows and Linux but in OS X the LiveConnect calls are broken since Java was upgraded to 7u51.

The applets are signed (Comodo), they have correct MANIFEST file (Permissions: all-permissions, Caller-Allowable-Codebase and Codebase are set). But JavaScript cannot call Java functions and the whole application gets broken.

Comment: *"In OS X, Firefox 26, Java 7u51 Liveconnect is broken?"*  It would not surprise me.  Why not raise a bug report with FF and see what they say?

Comment: What do you see in Java Console?

Comment: Java Control Panel => Advanced => Java console

Comment: Nothing strange there, the errors go to Firebug console since these are JS errors.